# Will dashboarding on Ultra-Nightmare cause your save file to be deleted?

Tags: doom-eternal

Working my way through an Ultra-Nightmare playthrough on Xbox and I wondered if dashboarding right before you die would delete your save or not. I already know that ending a level prematurely by exiting to the main menu will cause the save to be deleted, but if the game "crashes" (like what happens with dashboarding) will you be able to continue from your last completed level?

I would try this out myself but I already have two other save slots that I don't want to erase, and I'd rather not find out the hard way when I'm already

> to the gladiator fight on Taras Nabad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently dashboarding works as a way to cheese ultra-nightmare as per [this video](https://youtu.be/py8GysYpyh8) which outlines the strategy.

Be warned, doing this during the save where you unlock the rocket launcher can cause you to never unlock the rocket launcher.